# Right click: menu options

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

there is a feature I'd like to implement in my application:

The user right clicks on my picturebox object. Good.
When that happens, some code of mine executes and will generate a list of options.
Then a menu appears where the mouse right-clicked, made up of these options.
When the user clicks on one of these options, the menu is deleted and some code is run given the option index as parameter.

My two problems:

- How can I tell when the user right clicks? I can see an event handler for "click", but that includes left clicks....
- How do I create one of these menus? I mean, go ahead and right click something. That's the kind of menu I'm looking for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to implement the picturebox' MouseUp event.  Check if the right button was clicked, then create a ContextMenuStrip with the menu items you want.  You can use, say, the Tag property of the items you add to help identify them so you can give them a common Click event handler.  Like this:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    If e.Button <> Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then Return
    Dim cms = New ContextMenuStrip
    Dim item1 = cms.Items.Add("foo")
    item1.Tag = 1
    AddHandler item1.Click, AddressOf menuChoice
    Dim item2 = cms.Items.Add("bar")
    item2.Tag = 2
    AddHandler item2.Click, AddressOf menuChoice
    '-- etc
    '..
    cms.Show(PictureBox1, e.Location)
End Sub

Private Sub menuChoice(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim item = CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
    Dim selection = CInt(item.Tag)
    '-- etc
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

To your first question: you actually handle just the "click" event, there is no separate event for right-click. But look at the EventArgs object you get passed for the event: it includes information of which button was pressed (and would give you more info if a mouse click had anything beyond that). So you check the button within an `if` block, and you're good to go.

To your second question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx. If your menu is pre-defined, just look for that component on the Designer and prepare the menu from there and call its `Show()` method from the click handler. If you need to decide the menu entries on the fly, the linked documentation page actually includes an example on that ;)

PS: oops, I just noticed Jon's comment on the question. The answer I gave you is for Windows Forms. If you are on WPF let us know and I'll update with the details (although the concepts ain't too different).

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an easier way to do this. Double-click on the control you wish to be able to right click. Now go to the top of the page and it should say in comboboxes; 'Control' and 'Click' Click on the 'click' combobox and look for: Right-Click. Use a ContextMenuStrip for your right click menu.

Now you can choose which function you want.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_RightClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.RightClick
    ContextMenuStrip1.Show()
    MsgBox("Content Activated.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success!")
End Sub
```

Hope I could help. :)

Coridex73